# upstream prematurely closed connection while reading upstream (large files)

Tags: nginx, proxy, download, abort

So currently I'm a bit of a struggle. I serve large files on my ecommerce store (woocommerce), files around 10-30GB, we use x-accel-redirect/senfile for that.
Some users complained that the downloads abort at around 1 GB of time.
I've checked the nginx logs and found these errors.

```
upstream prematurely closed connection while reading upstream
```

and

```
upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream
```

So far I've found out that this has to do with the proxy_buffering right? I also think I found a solution for it

```
proxy_max_temp_file_size 0; 
proxy_buffering off;
```

would this solve the issue of the download aborting or is this the wrong solution?

Comment: your connection may have a timeout. try serving those file in chunks.